# How to work with git on a SVN repository

Tags: git, svn, version-control, repository, git-svn

I have the following problem.

I am working on a SVN repository and I am making changes to it but I don't want to commit them because the owner told me to not change anyhthing on the remote repository.

For other stuff I am using GIT and I like it more than SVN.

How can I do to have the SVN folder I am interested in, without moving it, to be version controlled through GIT?

Thanks in advance for your kind replies.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html

here you can find a dedicated blog series to see if the approach works for you

http://www.tfnico.com/presentations/git-and-subversion